# How to Export data from SQL database into MS Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

In my web application i want to **download data directly from a SQL database to MS Excel with customize heading**. In the web page there will be one textbox, user only choose the date from that textbox(this contain the pop up calender) and when user clicks on download button, it will directly download data into Excel.
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Check out this link http://seroter.wordpress.com/2011/03/24/exposing-on-premise-sql-server-tables-as-odata-through-windows-azure-appfabric/

Answer (score 1):

You build a dataset from the sql query and conert the dataset to excel file using the code snippet shown in [THIS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Globalking/datasettoexcel02272006232336PM/datasettoexcel.aspx) link.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyFiles.xls");
```

Now turn off caching, or some browser may unable to download and open the file.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Simple way, forget the code snippets, just bind a gridview and apply Big Fat Pig's codes... Gridview must be table layoutted